# PHP downloading file with custom file name doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a script that generates a zip file for download. I need to customize file name and zip file name. The download script like this:

```
public function download($jobId, $teacherId){
  // define file array
  $files = array(
      'certificate' => $file_url,
      'resume' => $file_url,
      'passport' => $file_url,
      'degree' => $file_url,
      'recommendation' => $file_url
  );

  // create new zip opbject
  $zip = new \ZipArchive();

  // create a temp file & open it
  $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
  $zip->open($tmp_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

  // loop through each file
  foreach($files as $name => $file){

    if (!empty($file)){
      // download file
      $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
      $file_name = $name . '.' . pathinfo($file)['extension'];

      // add it to the zip
      $zip->addFromString($file_name, $download_file);
    }
  }

  // close zip
  $zip->close();

  // send the file to the browser as a download
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'. preg_replace('/\s+/','', $teacher->name) .'.zip"'); // $teacher->name = Hoang Hiep
  header('Content-type: application/zip');
  // Disabled cache
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
  header('Pragma: private');
  readfile($tmp_file);
}
```

It's working well on my machine (MacOSX). But It doesn't work properly on the server. When I downloaded on my server it's always resonse default file name in a zip file and file download name: 'download.zip'. My expected to be 'HoangHiep.zip' ( if $teacher->name is Hoang Hiep ).

```
MacOSX 10.12.1:
PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: May 27 2016 12:20:55) 
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)

Ubuntu 16.04:
PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli)
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

I used Laravel 5.2.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the Laravel response helper: `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);`

Comment: I have tried using this. But no luck, same results, work well on my machine and doesn't work on my server. I think the cause of the problem is missing some config on the server. But I don't know what is it? So strange.

Comment: What are the headers you receive on both sides. Check out Chrome it will show you the headers on both cases

Comment: Response Headers

On my server:


`cf-ray:2fdf9e440faa3132-SIN
content-disposition:attachment; filename=download.zip
content-type:application/zip
date:Mon, 07 Nov 2016 09:04:56 GMT
server:cloudflare-nginx
status:200`

Comment: What about your Mac?

Comment: On my machine
`0:Content-type: application/zip
1:Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
2:Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="HoangHiep.zip"
Content-Length:15813856
Content-Type:application/zip
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Mon, 07 Nov 2016 09:07:48 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.22
Set-Cookie:xxx_session=%3D%3D; expires=Sat, 30-Jun-2018 09:07:48 GMT; Max-Age=51840000; path=/; secure; httponly
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.22`

Comment: Hopefully you noticed the differences: the quotes around the filename

Comment: Hmm, I think Cloudflare disabled headers response. What did you think?

Comment: Maybe, not sure about your architecture. Can you listen to the response directly without Cloudflare?

Comment: Do you try remove quotes? `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='. preg_replace('/\s+/','', $teacher->name) .'.zip');`, if it don't changed anything you can paste here also request header.

Comment: Yep, I have removed it. It don't changed anything.

Request headers:

`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=%3D%3D; edvntr_session=%3D%3D; driftt_aid=ea7ea144-5d8f-4079-902e-de034210d11c
Host:xx.xx.com
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Can you paste request on Mac and request on server?